# How to obtain static ip address for SSL on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to setup SSL for my Azure hosted Web Application.  I can't determine if I have a static I.P. address or not.  The documentation isn't very helpful.  The screenshot below indicates I have multiple outbound I.P. addresses?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This option shows about how to get the Static IP address of your website - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/05/05/how-to-get-a-static-ip-address-for-your-microsoft-azure-web-site/

The output IP addresses you are looking is different than a static public IP address. Once you assign and SSL binding it will generate a static IP.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you should keep in mind.

- If you click on Custom Domains in your app service settings you will have domain options as well as an ip that you can use for A record.
- If your app service is in a regular App Service Plan (Basic, Standard, Premium) it is on shared hardware and you do not have a real static ip assigned for say. If you want Isolation you can chose an App Service Plan that is an App Service Environment which they renamed to Isolation plan I think.
- You can use a cname record to point to your app service using the url they give you (AppServiceName.azurewebsites.net).
- I recommend using an azure traffic manager between your dns provider's mapping and your app service, this way you have more flexibility and ease for maintenance and upgrades.